# How to upload code to Arduino without a laptop

Tags: arduino-uno, hex

I would like to know is there a way of burning programs to microcontrollers like that on Arduino without using a computer? Like a pendrive or something? Suppose you want to update firmware on a utility end, must you carry the editable source code with you? How do the big companies do it?

Comment: SD card is possible. do you want a solution for Uno or is the tag random?

Comment: @Juraj Well I've been using Uno, nano and pro mini for now.

Comment: Are we talking strictly about solo Arduino boards? OTA (Over the Air) internet upload may be interesting feature for you

Answer (score 2):

One good way to update Uno/Nano/Mini without connecting it to a computer is to use SD bootloader. SD bootloader reads at boot the bin file with the update from the attached SD card and copies it to flash memory.

There are not many SD bootloader for ATmega. I use [avr_boot](https://github.com/zevero/avr_boot) by zevero. It works well. The downside is that it doesn't support upload over USB.

zevero doesn't offer built binaries of the bootloader so you have to compile it with the avr toolchain.

avr_boot requires a bin file, not a hex file, but it is simple to set Arduino IDE to create a bin file along with the hex file. You create platform.local.txt file next to platform.txt in the avr boards package, and put this line into the file:

```
## Create output (bin file)
recipe.objcopy.bin.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.elf2hex.cmd}" -O binary {compiler.elf2hex.extra_flags} "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf" "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin"
```

Then you can use "Export compiled binary" from Sketch menu in Arduino IDE and you will find the binary file next to your ino file in the sketch folder.

---

There are different ways how to update an Arduino without connecting it to computer. For small ATmega328p on Uno/Nano/Mini there is not enough flash space to do a self update. The code required to do the update takes more than half of the flash so there is no space left to store the update binary before applying it. (The updated sketch of course must have to have the code for the self update too.)

For illustration what is possible, [here is a sketch](https://github.com/JAndrassy/ArduinoOTA/blob/master/examples/Advanced/SD2Flash2BootAVRHex/SD2Flash2BootAVRHex.ino) for Arduino Mega which does a self update from SD card reading a hex file. It requires a modified Optiboot available in MegaCore.